# Add additional data to user profile via firestore functions onCreate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to automatically create a user data in my firestore db when user sign up through firestore functions. However I got 2 option for sign up. Bussiness account and personal account. If user signup as bussiness then I want to add "usertype = 1" into my document and when personal then "usertype=2" I managed to automaticaly create a document on signup via functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()

const db = admin.firestore()

exports.createUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
const uid = user.uid
const email = user.email
const newUserRef = db.collection("user").doc(uid)

return newUserRef.set({
    userId: uid,
    email: email
})
});
```

But how I can I also pass "usertype" into that function? Or which function to use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional information is passed into the `functions.auth.user().onCreate(` function, so  there's no way to distinguish between the two types of users there.

The best you can do is set the user-type from within the client by writing the same document from there. To prevent a race condition, you'll want to move the entire creation of the user-document to the client.

Comment: This is what I was affraid of... Thanks for cofirmation