# Firebase authentication aggregate data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have two different applications; let's call them A and B. I use Firestore to store additional user data under a collection called `/users`.

I have a cloud function that aggregates data whenever a user registers through Google, manual or Facebook to the `users` collection.

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate( (user, ctx) => {
 //aggregate data in /users
});
```

The problem is that I want to add another collection, say `different-users` that are only added when using application B. According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users):

> You cannot add other properties to the user object directly; instead,
>   you can store the additional properties in any other storage services,
>   like Google Cloud Firestore.

How am I supposed to differentiate these types of users in my *cloud* function giving the fact that I can't add additional data?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

The user is created in Firebase Authentication and *that* is what triggers your Cloud Function. At the point your backend code gets invoked, there is no information anymore about what app called the authentication API.

If you want to store additional information based on where the user was created from, consider calling a Callable Cloud Function directly from within your application code after the creation of the user in Firebase Authentication completes. Alternatively, you could write the info directly to the database from the client, if that works for your use-case.

Also see:

- [Add additional data to user profile via firestore functions onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262750/add-additional-data-to-user-profile-via-firestore-functions-oncreate) (which I now see is a duplicate, so I'll close against it in a minute)
- [Firebase Cloud Function - Create user with extra information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260206/firebase-cloud-function-create-user-with-extra-information/51276561#51276561)

Comment: Could you please edit your post and state there's on way to distinguish client origin on cloud functions?. And how does the client auth function differentiate when the user is logging in for the first time?.

Comment: I already answered that: "At the point your backend code gets invoked, there is no information anymore about what app called the authentication API."